# Set Variable values dynamically to run the ssis package fails

Tags: package, expression, ssis-2008

I have created SSIS package using VS 2008

I have 5 variables to dynamically change the value at run time

[image]

I have default values and I can change these values at run time.

I am running the package using bat file some thing like below

```
DTEXEC.EXE /FILE "C:\Users\katapa\Desktop\ExtractData.dtsx" 
/Set \Package.Variables[User::FilePath].Properties[Value];"C:\EPLInterface\PPSDataExtraction"
/Set \Package.Variables[User::Servername].Properties[Value];"New Server"
/Set \Package.Variables[User::DataBaseName].Properties[Value];"UAT"
/Set \Package.Variables[User::UserName].Properties[Value];"admin"
/Set \Package.Variables[User::Password].Properties[Value];"11111"
```

it always take the default values even I am updating the values.

When I run the package manually and set the parameters manually in the edit Command line it works. if I run the same code from external command line it takes the default values what I have set for variables.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This here will work - Its important that you dont have any breaks in your batch file. Så make sure everything is right after eachother and there is not brackets. This worked fine for me and i Tested it. The ECHO part can be deleted but is nice to use when debug

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
ECHO This is a batch file
ECHO.

DTEXEC.EXE /F "C:\Users\thoje\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\Integration Services Project8\Integration Services 
Project8\Package4.dtsx" /Set \Package.Variables[User::Test2].Value;lol  /set 
\Package.Variables[User::Test3].Value;omg
PAUSE
CLS
```

**The batfile without any enter/breaks**
[image]

**Without any breaks/enter push**

[image]

Comment: it's still takes the default values.